# boto3 s3.head_bucket returns 403 Forbidden only when reading from variable

Tags: python, variables, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this:

```
with open('my_file', 'r') as f_in:
    for i in f_in:
        response = s3.head_bucket(Bucket='i')
        print(response)
```

I expect to get bucket properties for those buckets that are in my_file but instead I get:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden

If I just put one bucket name it also fails

**If I hardcode the bucket name "(Bucket='my-bucketoweiruowi')", it works!**

If I get rid of the for loop:

```
var = 'my-bucketoweiruow'
response = s3.head_bucket(Bucket='var')
```

... it fails with the same 403 error

I removed the '' like this:

```
with open('my_file', 'r') as f_in:
    for i in f_in:
        response = s3.head_bucket(Bucket=i)
        print(response)
```

...but I get this other error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Bad Request".

I have 2 separate aws accounts with different buckets for testing. Same behavior.

Looks like when going into the loop it... breaks?

Comment: you are calling the bucket name 'line', that is not a variable. If it is a string variable, you wouldn't need `'`.

Comment: TY.  I replaced "line" for "i" and removed the ''.  Now I get "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Bad Request".  Looks like when going into the loop it... breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when 'my_file' is being read, for some reason, **when jumping to the next line, a a blank line is being added in between bucket names.**

That means that if I print the content using a for loop, I get this output:

bucket1

bucket2

bucket3

So if I remove such blank lines, the thing works fine:

```
with open('test','r') as f:
    for i in f:
        a = i.rstrip('\n')
        res = s3.head_bucket(Bucket=a)
        print(res)
```

Conclusion:  looks like the failure occurs when the function finds a blank line.